# Does the Talons card affect the Deck of Many Things?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Talons card in the Deck of Many Things says:

> Every magic item you wear or carry disintegrates. Artifacts in your possession aren't destroyed but do vanish.

and the Deck of Many Things is a magic item. **If you draw this card, is the deck itself destroyed?**

Answer (score 5):

Only if you're carrying it at the time.  You don't have to hold the deck in order to draw from it.  You can have it sitting on a table or something.

The more interesting question is whether or not the Talons card itself is destroyed if you are not carrying the whole deck.  I think that one's unclear enough for DM adjudication, though bias is to "no".  The Deck specifically lists which of its cards are self-destroying, and Talons isn't on the list.