# How dangerous can I make my tankard?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization

I bore of the savagery of combating my many adversaries, so I should like to outsource this chore to my tankard. By casting [*tiny servant*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-servant) on a single object (ie. my tankard) and presumably other spells, etc., how much damage would it be able to do?

- Metric: total average damage over three rounds dealt by the tankard. Assume area-of-effects hit two targets. Otherwise, targets can be assumed to within any particular reach or area. Damage must be reasonably applicable and not contingent of environment, ie. pushing things of cliff edges does not count.
- Any amount of setup time allowed, with the obvious limitation of *tiny servant* having a duration of 8 hours. The tankard also has the benefit of my actions on the first round (you may assume I am ahead of it in initiative; or any other particular order you wish) and my concentration during the whole time, but not my actions during the remaining turns.
- 20th level character using official character options (eg. no UA), including multiclassing and feats.
- Any magic items and boons are acceptable. As such my ability scores may be assumed to already be at their maximum of 30.
- Magic items and other resources may not be permanently expended, ie. no use of potions, scrolls, finite charges, the use of the final charge of an item which may be destroyed if the last one is used, nor consumed material components of spells with a specified cost. (This also excludes the non-replicative mode of *wish* as it risks me being unable to cast the spell again.)
- No assistance from others than me. The tankards proximity to me is up to the answerer to choose for their proposed strategy.
- Assume foes have an AC of 20 and a save modifier and check modifier of +10. They have no resistances, immunities, nor vulnerabilities and do not exist (for our purposes) until the three rounds of initiative start. Due to their hubris, they will not attack the tankard. (You may also assume they do not attack any other creature involved, if relevant to the method.)
- I should otherwise like the method to be target agnostic. There is a myriad of different creatures which have taken umbrage with me, so I can't have the method depend on (nor do I require it to account for) the creatures' type, (flying) speeds, resistances, shoe (or other) size, nor other properties.

Comment: I ask because I expect a lot of answers might want to use *animate objects*, but this seems mutually exclusive with *tiny servant* on a given target.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Except *animate objects* is 5th level, only lasts for a minute, and requires concentration. I'm having a hard time seeing how this would be preferable method for animating a single tiny object.

Comment: You appear to be set on making a fatal tankard, rather than a [Fatal Glass of Beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fatal_Glass_of_Beer_(1933_film)). Is cold resistance a requirement?

Comment: Are we allowed to polymorph the Tankard into a different creature entirely?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your final bullet point. Do you want answers to be able to take on any sort of monster, even ones with fly speeds or burrow speeds or anything of the sort? (I had assumed you meant that answers did *not* have to account for these things, but it seems a bit unclear)

Comment: @Medix2 The intent is to have the targets treated as generically as possible.

Answer (score 13):

**The highest average damage per round over three rounds that your tankard can deal is:**

#### 305.787

### The Character

The character (let's call her Callie) to command the most dangerous tankard has the following classes:

- Wizard 11------------------------------- (for *alter self*, *conjure minor elementals*, *haste*, *magic jar*, and *Tenser's transformation*)
- Warlock (The Undying) 9 ------------ (for *hold monster* and *death ward*)

...and the following magic items:

- a twenty-two card *deck of many things*
- a *robe of the archmagi*
- a *rod of the pact keeper*
- an *Ioun Stone of mastery*
- a *belt of storm giant strength*
- a *ring of air elemental command*
- a *scimitar of speed*
- three *javelins of lightning*<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> *Credit to [Medix2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/36521/medix2) for suggesting the javelins*

### Magic Jar

Firstly, Callie needs to be more proficient. A base proficiency bonus of +6 isn't good enough, so Callie has to take the body of a creature who is more generally proficient. This involves use of the *magic jar* spell, which lets her take the statistics of another humanoid, while keeping her class features.

She is looking for a humanoid of CR 21 or higher (to get a proficiency bonus of +7 or higher). Official options include:

- Halaster Blackcloak
- Quenthel Baenre
- any ancient metallic dragon who has used Change Shape to assume one such form

### Spell Glyphs

Then, we need to create a number of Spell Glyphs using *glyph of warding*. To avoid the material component cost, Callie will cast *glyph of warding* using the *wish* spell, but she [still needs to cast the stored spell as well](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136580/41726).

To gain access to *wish*...

- Callie casts *conjure minor elementals* choosing 8 CR 1/4 or lower elementals (retrying if the spell summons [chwinga](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chwinga) since they can't speak).
- Callie commands an elemental to repeatedly declare that they want to draw one card from the *deck of many things* (while Callie carries it, [so that the deck itself won't be desroyed if the elemental draws the **Talons** card](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151189/41726).
- Eventually, the elemental will draw the **The Fates** card.

  - If the **Donjon**, **Flames**, **Rogue**, **Skull**, or **The Void** card is drawn, kill the elemental or let the elemental die and try again.
- Callie commands the elemental to use **The Fates** to reverse a draw of either the **Donjon**, **Flames**, **Rogue**, **Skull**, **The Void**, **Ruin**, or **Talons** card.
- Then, Callie repeatedly declares that she wants to draw one card from the *deck of many things*.
- Eventually, Callie will draw the **Moon** card

  - If the elemental reverses a bad draw, restart with a new elemental.
- Cast *wish* to replicate the effect of *glyph of warding* for a Spell Glyph with one of the following spells:

  - many counts of *alter self*
  - *haste*
  - *Tenser's transformation*
- Repeat the whole procedure until you have ample Spell Glyphs.

### The Tiny Servant

Then, Callie's need the ideal Tiny Servant (we'll call him Tim). This involves the following procedure:

- Callie casts *tiny servant* on her tankard.
- Tim activates one of the *alter self* Spell Glyphs gaining the proper anatomy in order to speak.
- Tim repeatedly declares that he wants to draw one card from the *deck of many things*.
- Eventually, Tim will draw the **Moon** card for 3 castings of *wish*.

  - If the **Donjon**, **Flames**, **Rogue**, **Skull**, or the **The Void** card is drawn, kill Tim or let Tim die and try again.
  - Callie will have to make more *alter self* Spell Glyphs if she exhausts them all before a successful Tim.
- Tim attunes to the *belt of storm giant strength*, *scimitar of speed*, and *ring of air elemental command*
- Tim wields the *scimitar of speed* and a *javelin of lightning*.

### Combat Preparation

Now that Tim is ready, it is time to prepare for combat:

- Callie casts *death ward* on Tim
- Tim casts *wish* replicating the effect of an 8th level *delayed blast fireball* so that it will be on it's last 6 seconds of duration during Round 1.
- Tim activates the *haste*, *Tenser's transformation*, and a new *alter self* Spell Glyph (in order to speak command words).

### The Rounds

#### Round 1

**Callie:**

- Casts *hold monster* at 6th level on two targets that are nearby one another.
- Uses her bonus action each round to command Tim to take the listed actions.

**Tim:**

- Touches the *delayed blast fireball* (which will trigger *death ward*)
- Casts *wish* replicating the effect of an 8th level *wall of fire* placed in such a way that it will affect both targets, but not himself
- Attacks with the *scimitar of speed* as a bonus action.
- Hurls the *javelin of lightning* with the *haste* action so that it passes through one target to hit another.

#### Round 2:

- Tim draws a new *javelin of lightning*.
- Tim attacks with the *scimitar of speed* as a bonus action.
- Tim hurls the *javelin of lightning* with the *haste* action so that it passes through one target to hit another.
- Tim casts *wish* replicating the effect of an 8th level *vitriolic sphere*.

#### Round 3:

- Tim draws a new *javelin of lightning*.
- Tim attacks with the *scimitar of speed* as a bonus action.
- Tim hurls the *javelin of lightning* with the *haste* action so that it passes through one target to hit another.
- Tim casts *chain lightning*<sup>2</sup> with the *ring of air elemental command*.

<sup>2</sup> *Credit to [GcL](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/38434/gcl) for mentioning that* chain lightning *is superior to* disintegrate *against multiple targets*

### The Calculation

#### Hold Monster

To start with, it is impossible for any of the targets to succeed on the saving throw of *hold monster*.

- Callie's spell save DC is 31

  - 8 (base) + 8 (+7 proficiency bonus from *magic jar* statistics +1 from *Ioun Stone of mastery*) + 10 (Charisma) + 2 (*robes of the archmagi*) + 3 (*rod of the pact keeper*)

#### Round 1

- *Delayed blast fireball* deals 13d6 base damage and 10d6 ticking damage to both targets.

  - 23 * 3.5 * 2 = **161** fire damage
- *Wall of fire* deals 9d8 damage to both targets.

  - 9 * 4.5 * 2 = **81** fire damage
- *Scimitar of speed* deals 1d6 + 2d12 (*Tenser's transformation*) + 11 on a hit, or 2d6 + 4d12 + 11 on a critical hit.

  - 81.25% chance of a regular hit yields **11.78125** slashing damage and **10.5625** force damage.
  - 9.75% chance of a critical hit yields **1.755** slashing damage and **2.535** force damage.
- *Javelin of lightning* deals 4d6 damage to one target and 5d6 + 2d12 + 9 damage to the other on a hit, or 10d6 + 4d12 + 9 damage on a critical hit.

  - 4 * 3.5 = **14** lightning damage
  - 74.25% chance of a regular hit yields **9.28125** piercing damage, **9.6525** force damage, and **10.395** lightning damage.
  - 9.75% chance of a critical hit yields **1.56** piercing damage, **2.535** force damage, and **2.73** lightning damage.
- *Wall of fire* deals 9d8 damage to both targets.<sup>3</sup>

  - 9 * 4.5 * 2 = **81** fire damage

In Round 1, Tim deals an expected **323** fire damage, **13.53625** slashing damage, **25.285** force damage, **27.125** lightning damage, and **10.84125** piercing damage.

<sup>3</sup> *Credit to [Medix2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/36521/medix2) for mentioning that* wall of fire *deals damage twice in Round 1 if Tim acts before the targets.*

#### Round 2

- *Wall of fire* deals 9d8 damage to both targets.

  - 9 * 4.5 * 2 = **81** fire damage
- *Scimitar of speed* deals 1d6 + 2d12 (*tenser's transformation*) + 11 on a hit, or 2d6 + 4d12 + 11 on a critical hit.

  - 81.25% chance of a regular hit yields **11.78125** slashing damage and **10.5625** force damage.
  - 9.75% chance of a critical hit yields **1.755** slashing damage and **2.535** force damage.
- *Javelin of lightning* deals 4d6 damage to one target and 5d6 + 2d12 + 9 damage to the other on a hit, or 10d6 + 4d12 + 9 damage on a critical hit.

  - 4 * 3.5 = **14** lightning damage
  - 74.25% chance of a regular hit yields **9.28125** piercing damage, **9.6525** force damage, and **10.395** lightning damage.
  - 9.75% chance of a critical hit yields **1.56** piercing damage, **2.535** force damage, and **2.73** lightning damage.
- *Vitriolic sphere* deals 18d4 damage to both targets.

  - 18 * 2.5 * 2 = **90** acid damage

In Round 2, Tim deals an expected **81** fire damage, **13.53625** slashing damage, **25.285** force damage, **27.125** lightning damage, **10.84125** piercing damage, and **90** acid damage.

#### Round 3

- *Vitriolic sphere* deals 5d4 damage to both targets.

  - 5 * 2.5 * 2 = **25** acid damage
- *Wall of fire* deals 9d8 damage to both targets.

  - 9 * 4.5 * 2 = **81** fire damage
- *Scimitar of speed* deals 1d6 + 2d12 (*tenser's transformation*) + 11 on a hit, or 2d6 + 4d12 + 11 on a critical hit.

  - 81.25% chance of a regular hit yields **11.78125** slashing damage and **10.5625** force damage.
  - 9.75% chance of a critical hit yields **1.755** slashing damage and **2.535** force damage.
- *Javelin of lightning* deals 4d6 damage to one target and 5d6 + 2d12 + 9 damage to the other on a hit, or 10d6 + 4d12 + 9 damage on a critical hit.

  - 4 * 3.5 = **14** lightning damage
  - 74.25% chance of a regular hit yields **9.28125** piercing damage, **9.6525** force damage, and **10.395** lightning damage.
  - 9.75% chance of a critical hit yields **1.56** piercing damage, **2.535** force damage, and **2.73** lightning damage.
- *Chain lightning* deals 13d6 + 40 damage on both targets.

  - 10 * 4.5 * 2 = **90** lightning damage

In Round 3, Tim deals an expected **25** acid damage, **81** fire damage, **13.53625** slashing damage, **25.285** force damage, **117.125** lightning damage, and **10.84125** piercing damage.

**The three round average DPR for Tim is *161.667* fire damage, *13.536* slashing damage, *24.285* force damage, *57.125* lightning damage, *10.841* piercing damage, and *38.333* acid damage, totaling *305.787* damage.**

Comment: How do you address the issue where if the The Talons card is drawn before The Fates card is, you would lose the whole deck?

Comment: Also, the cards vanish after being drawn from the DoMT. This plan would require multiple decks and I think that runs afoul of the rule regarding not using non-renewable resources.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The cards don't vanish forever; they reappear in the deck: "Once a card is drawn, it fades from existence. Unless the card is the Fool or the Jester, **the card reappears in the deck**, making it possible to draw the same card twice."

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The familiar isn't the one wearing or carrying the deck (which is what the Talons card affects), Callie is.

Comment: You may want to see if there is some support for the supposition that you can draw from the deck without possessing it. This DM would consider your interpretation contrary to the intent, preferring to assume that when you draw you possess the deck for a brief duration to permit you to draw.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Moonblades

The basic idea here is to use infinite damage moonblades to do infinite damage per hit.  However, since our damage is limited by the hp of our opponents, this does not convert to infinite damage.

#### Step one-- change form

A tankard doesn't get multiattack and we can't easily give it levels in fighter.  Ergo we must first change its form (probably via *True Polymorph* back into a regular tankard and then *True Polymorph* again into a CR 9 tiny monster and then again into the final creature,  the second overriding the 'less potent' polymorph, and then itself being dispelled via *Dispel Magic*, but anything that replaces statistics can work) so that it gains multiattack.  The best we can do appears to be three attacks via the Gladiator-- while the quadrone gets more attacks and they are with weapons they are only with bows while moonblades are longswords.

Moonblades only bond with elves and half-elves, so normally we'd have to change into an elf, attune the moonblade, and then change into our final form.  However, since gladiators can be elven, we can just go straight to being an elven gladiator.

Form changing is allowed by your question, of course, but if you don't like it, just subtract two attacks per round from the final result and use the Fates card method in the 'improvements' section at the end-- the rest of the work will be the same.

#### Step two-- buff

We want buffs.  Our main character will concentrate on *Haste* for us, cast *Wish* to duplicate the effects of *True Seeing* for us without the 25 gp component a round before the fight, and give us a *Sanctuary* effect on the first round. We will also be subject to *Fire Shield* (both versions), *Hallow* with Extradimensional Interference, *Foresight*, *Freedom of Movement*, *Mind Blank*, and *Longstrider*.

Additionally, we will be mounted upon a *Broom of Flying*, wearing attuned *Claws of the Umber Hulk*, assuming 'can't manipulate objects' is taken to mean 'can't Use an Object action' and not 'can't wield weapons, wear armor, consume rations, or otherwise do anything involving objects', and wearing an attuned *Belt of Storm Giant Strength*.  Our Gladiator also is attuned to a *dancing moonblade* with infinite runes.

Our *moonblade* can store spells in it but there's nothing great 5th level or lower to put in it, I don't think, since we already have *haste*.  *Counterspell* seems like a good choice.

### Step three-- combat

On the first round we are well-protected against hostile immobilizing effects by our myriad defenses, especially *Sanctuary*.  Once it is our turn we fly, burrow, or run over to the nearest enemy and Multiattack it with our *dancing moonblade*.  We have advantage on the attack because *Foresight*, and with our *belt* and *moonblade* we have a total to-hit bonus of +15.  We hit on a 5+, which is a 96% chance of success.  We kill anything we hit with our infinite damage, dealing its hp in effective damage.  We've now broken *Sanctuary* so enemies no longer have to make a DC 24 Wisdom save to do anything mean to us.  We then continue moving to the next target, hitting it with a 96% chance of success as well.  We do this again for our final attack of our multiattack, then for our *Haste* attack, then loose the weapon to attack with a bonus action via the *dancing* property, again with a 96% chance of success, using our free object interaction to pick it up again when it's done, positioning ourselves so that an enemy will, it its insane hubris, move right past us taking the shortest route towards the main character, thus provoking an attack of opportunity.

On our next turns, we continue to attempt to kill up to 6 enemies per round with a 96% chance of success each.  We have advantage on any saves they might make us make, and protection (including retaliatory damage) if they give up on the whole infinite hubris thing and attack us.  We can deal with flying, burrowing, invisible, ethereal, teleporting, and climbing creatures.  We deal infinite slashing, fire, cold, acid, lightning, and thunder damage, so unless a creature is immune to *all* of those (e.g. because it is subject to an ongoing *Invulnerability* spell) it will take infinite damage on a hit and thus die.

We may have to adjust our tactics if the enemies prove especially problematic.  For example, we can only go 40 feet underground per round so if there are only enemies underground and they are far enough apart we may not be able to get 6 in a round.  We are immune to most control effects, but certain readied actions, like a readied *wall of force* or *antimagic field* could prove disastrous for us.  If creatures ready such spells, we need to avoid them.  Similarly, if a creature readies an action to grab our dancing weapon, we may need to kill that target normally to avoid risking a <4% chance we lose our weapon after it misses and their attempt to grab it is successful.

Assuming the creatures helpfully march forwards and let us kill them, though, we do an average of 96%*6*their average hp in damage per round.

## Improvements

*Swift Quiver* is faster than a *dancing moonblade*, and we can cast it from spell storing, but it needs a weapon with ammo.  Since gunblades aren't a thing in official 5e land, not even for absurd infinite damage moonblades, that means it is only better if the hardiest creatures around are going to be killed or almost killed by a +3 Oathbow.

If that 4% miss rate bothers us, we can improve it.  A Boon of Fate on our main character takes no actions and can add 1d10 on a miss that isn't a 1, but we can only do it once in the fight.  If we [farm Fate cards](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/164644/14848), we need not miss so often.  There's a 1 in 20 chance we get a Fates card from the deck per draw (2 cards are already permanently missing so we don't break the consumption rules), and a 1 in 6 chance we draw Fates before we have to use a safety Fate and retry.  If we assume only one creature can draw per round, and that drawing takes an action, we on average draw something like 5 Fates an hour.  The odds of getting at least 18 Fates (enough to ensure every attack hits) are [very very very good](https://onlinegdb.com/B1ER_PM7I).

Comment: I'm not sure that turning the tankard into a gladiator means its still a tankard... Also why are you making the "tankard" defensive when "Due to their hubris, they (the enemies) will not attack the tankard."

Comment: Is step 1 *true polymorph*?

Comment: If the firsst step (or any step, really) involves changing the tankard into something else for the duration of the fight, then it's no longer "how much can the Tankard do" it's "how much can the strongest beastie I can find in the MM do?"

Comment: @NautArch Yes it is, but anything with a similar effect could also work (though I am unaware of anything)

Comment: Gotcha, it may help to specify those mechanics in your answer just so it's clear how you achieve it.

Comment: @Medix2 Because there are lots of dangers besides the attack action. The question says "I should otherwise like the method to be target agnostic. There is a myriad of different creatures which have taken umbrage with me, so I can't have the method depend on (nor do I require it to account for) the creatures type, (flying) speeds, resistances, shoe (or other) size, nor other properties."  There's no 'default being', so not relying on the opponent not having a fly speed means being able to deal with that if it happens.  Same for ranged attackers, swarms, spell casters, etc.

Comment: @RevenantBacon No, object-->creature only goes to CR 9.  Also if we could pick any creature we would want the creature with the most melee attacks that could be moonblades instead of what they are.  That's hardly the 'strongest beastie'.

Comment: The thing you've quoted says that the solution does **not** have to account for fly speeds or distance or anything of the sort.

Comment: @Medix2 Right, but it also says your solution has to work *regardless* of fly speeds etc.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Once you animate the tankard with *Tiny Servant*, it is no longer an object and becomes a creature, so the Object -> Creature rules for *True Polymorph* no longer apply, and you instead need to use the Creature -> Creature rules. As the servant is CR 0 and has no class levels, you need to use a CR 0 creature if you're polymorphing it. And if you're polymorphing it *back into a tankard* then you're no longer using the *Tiny Servant* spell.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Fortunately 1) the tankard isn't CR 0 2) the tankard becoming an object doesn't end the *tiny servant spell*, it just suppresses its effects

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil 1) *Yes it is* 2) You can't hit it with two *True Polymorphs* at once, since a creature cannot be affected by multiple instances of the same spell at once only the first will take effect. Additionally, since *True Polymorph* is a concentration spell, once you start casting the second spell, the first ends, reverting it back into a *Tiny Servant*, and therefore subject to the CR restrictions previously mentioned.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil On the bright side, you've inspired me to ask a question regarding the interactions of multiple different polymorph type effects ending on the same target at different times.

Comment: @RevenantBacon 1)https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/27/what-is-the-cr-for-a-tiny-servant-in-xanathars/amp/ 2) https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects 3) hope your new question is fruitful :)

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil 1) tweets from JC are no longer considered official errata, only Sage Advice. If it has no CR, then that means that either A) you can only polymorph it into something else with no CR, B) that means it is treated as an effective CR of 0, or possibly C) it's an invalid target 2) that's fair 3) seems to be good so far. Side note, one thing I've remembered about the spell is that Object -> Creature cannot exceed the size of the object, ie tiny tankard -> medium creature is a no-go.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Not having a CR means that you can't turn it into any creatures, even CR 0 creatures.  You can still, of course, turn it into an object.